# How to play audio from file with raw big-endian 16-bit signed values using Java

Tags: java, audio

I have a program that's generating an audio waveform as a short[] (signed, big-endian, 44.1KHz mono), then writing it to a file. It's not a .wav file, or any other codec... it's literally just a few megabytes of raw 16-bit samples.

I have *another* program that's attempting to open that file and play it. The following code throws `javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: Stream of unsupported format`:

```
        float sampleRate = 44100;
        int sampleSizeBits = 16;
        int numChannels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeBits, numChannels, signed, bigEndian);

        BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE));

// The next line is the one that's throwing the exception
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputStream);

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        sourceDataLine.open(format);
        sourceDataLine.start();

        byte[] bufferBytes = new byte[4096];
        int readBytes = -1;
        while ((readBytes = audioStream.read(bufferBytes)) != -1) {
            sourceDataLine.write(bufferBytes, 0, readBytes);
        }
        sourceDataLine.drain();
        sourceDataLine.close();
        audioStream.close();
```

### Update

Based on tgdavies' comment, it looks like AudioInputStream isn't actually *capable* of reading audio from a file that's literally a sequence of byte pairs encoding raw big-endian signed 16-bit values. When I stepped through the call to AudioFormat.getAudioInputStream(), it only tried the following types of audio file readers:

- WaveExtensibleFileReader
- WaveFloatFileReader
- WaveFileReader
- SoftMidiAudioFileReader
- AuFileReader
- AiffFileReader

So... does this mean Java doesn't *have* an audio library method that allows reading directly from a file containing nothing but raw signed 16-bit sample values, encoded as big-endian pairs of bytes?

Is there some OTHER library I can use, or do I have to go back and figure out how to write the data into something like a proper .wav file?

Finally... if anyone happens to know... is it actually *necessary* to handle reading the file and spoonfeeding it to sourceDataLine.write() myself? Or is there some nice convenience method that allows you to say, "here's a file, it contains raw audio data in {this format}... spawn a Thread, read it, play it, then call {some method} on {class implementing the callback} when you're done to let me know?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat and see exactly what's happening.

Comment: An AudioFileReader which read that would match *any* file, so you wouldn't be able to read any specific format file with that provider installed. Id suggest writing a WAV header on your files, or creating your own `AudioFileReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tgdavies' help, I was able to get it to work by writing the short[] as a proper .wav file, then playing it (code follows).

The first problem I had to overcome was figuring out how to transform a short[] (containing raw signed 16-bit PCM samples) into a byte[] (in big-endian order). I came up with this:

```
// pcm16 is the short[]
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(pcm16.length * 2);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
ShortBuffer shortBuffer = byteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
shortBuffer.put(pcm16);
byte[] rawBytes = byteBuffer.array();
```

I have no idea whether this is even remotely close to being the optimal way to get from short[] to byte[]... if anyone has any better ideas, please comment so I can make it better.

Once I had the byte[], I wrote it to a .wav file as follows:

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 1, true, true);
AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawBytes), audioFormat, rawBytes.length);
File file = new File("tempfile.wav");
try {
    ais.reset();
    if (file.exists)
        file.delete();
    AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.toString());
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The next problem I ran into was that my original playback code started throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip cannot be cast to javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine

I found the answer in another SO post: [java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip cannot be cast to javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647505/java-lang-classcastexception-com-sun-media-sound-directaudiodevicedirectclip-c)

The solution came more or less directly from pfurbacher's answer:

```
public void play(URL url, CountDownLatch outerLatch) {
        CountDownLatch syncLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        System.out.println("playing " + url.getFile());
        
        // Use try-with-resources to ensure the stream and clip are closed.
        try (AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();) {

            clip.addLineListener(e -> {
                if (e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                    syncLatch.countDown();
                }
            });
            
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
            syncLatch.await();
            while (clip.getFramePosition() < clip.getFrameLength()) {
                Thread.yield();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        outerLatch.countDown();

    }

    private URL getUrl(final File file) {
        try {
            return file.toURI().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

... and all of my original playback code got replaced by:

```
play(getUrl(new File("tempfile.wav")));
```

Note: the code above isn't *exactly* what I had in my own program... I edited it a bit to make it more readable, and in the process removed a LOT of error-handling code that really ought to be in there & replaced it with the try/catch for a generic Exception. Nevertheless, this will hopefully help someone else who finds themselves in a situation where they're trying to figure out how to get from a short[] of raw PCM data to actual audio playback.